# How can I edit the html of the title of my node page

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content-type "foo" and some nodes with that type. Now, if you go to one of the node pages, e.g. /node/22, you see the node title as the page title.

I can edit the html of the whole page using node--foo.tpl.php but I can't edit the title/titles html.

How can I change the html of the title div on such a page for a specific content-type?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your current theme, the title may be found in the `node.tpl.php`, the `page.tpl.php` (usually this one) or `html.tpl.php`. Enable theme debugging to toggle theme debug comments. That way, you see which templates control which portions of the page.

Add the following to `settings.php` and refresh a couple of times (clear cache if it becomes stubborn). Then inspect the page.

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = true;
```

With theme debugging on, you'll also see the progression of template name suggestions in the comments, with the top most/most specific/longest name being selected first.

You can also add to this list by altering the `theme_hook_suggestions` property in the variables argument of the appropriate `hook_preprocess_` hook. If I remember correctly, there's no suggestion content type suggestion for templates. If so, you'll have to add one.